# basic understanding: binding methods with arguments to controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, command

I have a window with a `ListBox` that is bound to an instance of `List<MyThing>`. The class `MyThing` contains a property `Name` which is displayed in the `ListBox`.

I also have a `Button`, and I want to run the following method when it is clicked:

```
void RunMe(MyThing m) { ... }
```

As the parameter for this method I want to use the `SelectedItem` from the `ListBox`.

**How do I do that?**

This is my XAML file for the `MyWindow` class:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding MyThingList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Run command!" Command="{Binding RunCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The `DataContext` of `MyWindow` is set to an instance of `MyVM`, defined below.
The codebehind of this XAML is empty except for `InitializeComponent`.

And here is my ViewModel class `MyVM`:

```
public class MyVM
{
    public IList<MyThing> MyThingList { get; private set; }

    public MyVM(IList<MyThing> aThingList)
    {
        MyThingList = aThingList;
        RunCommand = // somehow connect it to method "RunMe"
    }

    public void RunMe(MyThing m) { ... }

    public ICommand RunCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

As the experienced of you might see, I don't really know what I am doing. So here are some concrete questions:

1. Why can't I simply bind the button to any METHOD that is called whenever I click? Why does it have to be a command, what is the benefit? (I know that a command can automatically keep track of its executability, greying out the button when it cannot be executed, but for now, I don't care about this. I also know that it can bind to an event, but it seems this event must be defined in the codebehind, which I want to keep empty. Correct me if I'm wrong.)
2. How do I connect my `RunMe` method to the command `RunCommand` inside the constructor of `MyVM`? (I have tried `RunCommand = new RoutedUICommand("RunMe", "RunMe", typeof(MyVm));`, but then the button is greyed out. I also tried `typeOf(MyWindow)` and `typeof(Window)`, but it's still greyed out.)
3. Assume I got this working such that a button click results in calling the method `RunMe`. How do I hand the `SelectedItem` from the `ListBox` to the `RunMe` method? (I know I can change the `DataContext` of the button to `DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=lb}"`, but then the command will probably not be found, and I still don't know how to make the button hand over this selected item to the method.)
4. Is there maybe something fundamentally wrong with my approach? I am still trying to get a hang of anything (GUI programming in general, events/commands, WPF, MVVM pattern - it's all new to me at the same time), so if you have better ways of doing this, please tell me.

PS: Please feel free to change the title to sth more expressive. I have so many questions that it is hard to nail it down to one...

Comment: "Why can't I simply bind the button to any METHOD that is called whenever I click?" Because `ICommand` is more generalized and powerful. If I were you I would steal a `DelegateCommand` implementation from somewhere and use that. [MS Prism has one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410(v=pandp.50).aspx). WPF should come with a DelegateCommand right out of the box, IMHO. That's a real oversight on their part.

Comment: You pass a `CommandParameter` to the Command by binding it to the `Button.CommandParameter` property. Easy peasy.

Comment: That's why MVVM frameworks are being built. If you're already using one - check it's documentation, you may find something that addresses your needs. If not use Caliburn.Micro actions: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions - they do all you want.

Answer (score 2):

`ICommand` is far more flexible and powerful than a simple method call. If you do want a simple method call (well, *kinda* simple... ish), you can just handle the Button's `Click` event:

```
protected void RunCommandButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    var vm = (MyVM)DataContext;
    var selectedThing = lb.SelectedItem as MyThing;

    if (selectedThing != null)
    {
        vm.RunMe(selectedThing);
    }
}
```

That's not "The Right Way", but sometimes it's good enough. We don't always need to build the Parthenon. Sometimes we just need a tarp to keep the rain off the firewood.

If you're using a command (and you should learn to use commands), you should use a `DelegateCommand` to implement your command. WPF should have included such a thing right out of the box, but unfortunately they didn't. What they do provide is very painful to figure out on your own. [MS Prism has one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410(v=pandp.50).aspx), though I haven't used it. Below I've included a very simple non-generic version.

```
private DelegateCommand _runCommand;
public ICommand RunCommand {
    get {
        if (_runCommand == null)
        {
            _runCommand = new DelegateCommand(RunCommandExecute, ExecuteCanExecute);
        }
        return _runCommand;
    }
}

protected void RunCommandExecute(Object parameter)
{
    //  Do stuff
}

protected bool RunCommandCanExecute(Object parameter)
{
    //  Return true if command can be executed
    return parameter != null;
}
```

Bind like so:

```
<Button 
    Content="Run command!" 
    Command="{Binding RunCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lb}"
    />
```

Also, use an `ObservableCollection<T>` for your list items rather than `List<T>`. That way, when you add and remove list items, the list box will update automagically.

DelegateCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace HollowEarth.MVVM
{
    public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        #region Constructors
        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action execute)
            : this(o => execute(), null)
        {
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = o => execute();
            _canExecute = o => canExecute();
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion Constructors

        public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why can't I simply bind the button to any METHOD that is called whenever I click? Why does it have to be a command, what is the benefit?

The `Command` pattern is mainly meant to be used in MVVM, because as you said it allows the view and the viewmodel to share information, like `CanExecute` type of methods; you can kind of "bind" a button to any method without using this pattern, by using its `Click` event.

Moreover, Commands are an abstraction between the view and the viewmodel; if you could use any method, your view could... well, use any method exposed by your viewmodel.

That being said, this is just a pattern and you don't *have* to use it. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035372/when-to-use-event-and-command-for-wpf-mvvm) for an example about Caliburn.Micro, which it would seem doesn't use Commands.

> 2. How do I connect my RunMe method to the command RunCommand inside the constructor of MyVM?

We're going to need your ICommand implementation to answer this.

> 3. Assume I got this working such that a button click results in calling the method RunMe. How do I hand the SelectedItem from the ListBox to the RunMe method?

In MVVM, think data, not view.
You should have a `List` (or an `ObservableCollection` if it needs to be modified in real time) in your viewmodel that contains the items that your ListBox's ItemsSource should bind to in XAML.
In the same vein, you'll need a CurrentItem property in your viewmodel, to which your ListBox's SelectedItem will bind.

`<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding MyList} SelectedItem={Binding CurrentItem}/>`

> 4. Is there maybe something fundamentally wrong with my approach? I am still trying to get a hang of anything

Nothing wrong per se, WPF and MVVM are a steep learn. You'll need some time before you get comfortable with them.

Comment: Just a point about the 'Caliburn.Micro' example: The framework still uses the command model, it simply creates the commands and bindings on the fly based on a naming convention.